# where is the place in Eclipse to add something to ignore list of SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn

I want to tell SVN in Eclipse to ignore these when I check in the code.
where is the place to go to set this ignore list:

```
.classpath
.project
.settings*
target
```

Comment: Are asking how to remove these from version control?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Select project > Team > Synchronize with Repository.

Then right-click on file, select "Add to svn:ignore"

Or go to Window > Preferences > Team > Ignored Resources and add the patterns there.

Comment: Ok I will use this way:  Window > Preferences > Team > Ignores Resources  .   could not find it in Project ->Team ->Sync ...actually in project menu I do not see a Team option, I hope it is not another issue but could find it through Window > Preferences > Team

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you ignore the file type BEFORE commiting to repository since SVN doesn't allow you to ignore a committed file or type.

Comment: Yes it seem the only way to fix that is to start over with a new "Share Project" painful..

Answer (score 5):

You can add them as svn properties using a command line client or the TeamSynchronizing menu via the "Add to svn:ignore" sub menu.

With a svn client :

```
svn propset svn:ignore .classpath .
svn propset svn:ignore .project .
svn propset svn:ignore .settings* .
svn propset svn:ignore target .
```

Answer (score 3):

Right-click the file or directory you want to exclude from version control, then choose Team > Add to svn:ignore to display the Add to svn:ignore dialog.

Answer (score 3):

If you've already committed the .project and / or the .classpath files, all is not lost!

Delete the .project and / or .classpath files manually: you can use the command line, for example, or go to your project in a navigator window (not Eclipse) where you will need to show hidden files.

Refresh your project in Eclipse, and it'll give you plenty of errors.

Commit (by right-clicking your project) the fact that the files are deleted.

Then you can rebuild your project to get rid of the errors.

Answer (score 1):

To check list of ignored items:
Right click on the project -> Team -> Show properties -> 'svn:ignore' item in the table